# NPM error when installing globally even when directories are writable

Tags: node.js, npm

i have this error when try to install coffee-script using this command:

```
npm install -g --verbose coffee-script opal
```

these are the error message:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm info postuninstall opal@0.3.2
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/opal/bin/opal-node'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/opal/bin/opal-node']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/opal/bin/opal-node' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

the folder /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib/node_modules are owned and writable by current user, and i do not want to run that npm command using root, how to know which folder that the npm tried to make a symlink to?

i'm using npm 1.2.9-1chl1~quantal1 and nodejs 0.8.19-1chl1~quantal1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

your node installation uses system directories.  Use sudo when using -g

```
sudo npm install -g --verbose coffee-script opal
```

Comment: Is there anything inherently unsafe about doing this?

Comment: I wouldn't feel comfortable doing it that way.  I'd rather install node in way that does not require sudo.

Comment: `sudo npm remove -g name-of-module`

Comment: `sudo npm` is discouraged by the author of `npm`, see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787931/1614973

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev indeed, it is, but in the OP case, that was the easiest to get him out of his predicament.  Fixing the permissions on his npm caches is not a single shot type solution.

Comment: Yes - it is the easiest, but leads to more troubles in the future. I've burnt through it myself and like to warn others - it is the worse solution out of the two.

Answer (score 15):

You can `chown` NPM's `bin` to your user name with this one liner to solve this problem:

```
$ chown -R `whoami` `npm -g bin`
```

Comment: careful! changes ownership everything in `/usr/bin/` (e.g., `sudo` also)

Answer (score 4):

ah, using this command:

```
npm -g bin
```

it would output something like this:

```
/usr/bin # this is the folder nodejs wanted to write..
```

then you may `chmod` or `chown` it so it can be written for installation.

Comment: This is helpful information but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem at [NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo/19354387), the issue was that **when i installed node i did it with sudo via chris/lea ppa repo**.

My solution was to uninstall node and then install it this way:

Download latest stable node sources from nodejs.org #in my case node-v0.10.20.tar.gz

> tar -zxf node-v0.10.20.tar.gz #uncompress sources
>
> cd node-v0.10.20 #enter uncompressed folder
>
> sudo chown $USER -R /usr/local
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install

PD: **If you don't want to change ownership of the /usr/local folder**, you can install it somewhere you already own. The problem of this approach is that you will have to bind the installation folder with the bash command line so that we can use the node command later on

> mkdir ~/opt
>
> ./configure --prefix=~/opt && make && make install
>
> echo 'export PATH=~/opt/bin:${PATH}' >> ~/.bashrc #or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshenv depending on the current Operative System

With either of those approaches, you will be able to do the following without using sudo

> npm install -g --verbose coffee-script opal

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Turns out I had something in `project/node_modules` directory installed with `sudo`. In my case it was some of the dependencies AND ALSO `.bin` directory. I deleted these bad directories, then ran `npm install` again and it succeeded. I did also reinstall global protractor and phantomjs, but not sure if that was required. I am sure it was the bad (i.e. root-owned) `.bin` directory causing this.

Comment: You did not have to delete the "bad" directories, just set their permissions and/or ownerships as explained in other answers.