# Could not install appium using ' npm install -g appium ' command

Tags: npm

I have installed node on mavericks using 'brew install node'. Node is installed. But npm version is not shown.

```
$ node -v 
v0.10.26

$ npm -v 
-bash: npm: command not found

$ npm install -g appium 
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Please help.

Comment: $ brew install npm 
Warning: node-0.10.26 already installed

Comment: Kindly use this link for brew installation process for appium.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android/23738169#23738169

Answer (score 1):

Please try re installing node from the installer package available at http://nodejs.org/

If does not work

try running `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/` from Terminal and reinstall node.js