# How to install and run appium in linux?

Tags: android, ui-automation, appium, android-uiautomator

I want to do UI automation for opening an url in a real android device. For that I want to install and run appium on my linux system, please guide me how to do? Also suggest me Is there anyway to open an url in chrome browser using eclipse??

Comment: follow this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android 

It will help You dear

Comment: This question has the answer you need. It worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android

Answer (score 7):

**Install appium on Linux 18.04**

If you have node.js installed you can try  :

```
sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I guess all the information you need to run Appium in Linux is in this here:

http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/

how to run your test

http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#running-tests

and a bunch of sample code here

https://github.com/appium/sample-code

and if you want to run your test in Chrome Browser you will need Chromedriver, it's already integrated in the appium project. More info here:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Comment: First link given above is dead. May be moved.

Answer (score 1):

---

### Install Appium on Linux(Fedora 22)

```
$ sudo dnf update -y
$ sudo dnf groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
$ sudo dnf install -y autoconf automake libtool gettext git scons cmake flex bison libcurl-devel curl ncurses-devel ruby bzip2-devel expat-devel
$ git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew.git ~/.linuxbrew
```

#### Until LinuxBrew is fixed, the [following is required.](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/issues/47)

Add to `.bashrc`:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

## Setup linux brew

```
export LINUXBREWHOME=$HOME/.linuxbrew
export PATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/bin:$PATH
export MANPATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/man:$MANPATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/lib64/pkgconfig:$LINUXBREWHOME/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/lib64:$LINUXBREWHOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


$ ln -s $(which gcc) ~/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-4.4
$ ln -s $(which g++) ~/.linuxbrew/bin/g++-4.4
$ brew update

$ brew install node      # get node.js
$ npm install -g appium  # get appium
$ npm install wd         # get appium client
$ appium &               # start appium
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello appium installation is very simple , please check below steps

1)Install Latest Node.js

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

More information please check official website : https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

2) Install latest Appium

```
npm install -g appium
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g appium
```

More information please check official documentation :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium

Answer (score 0):

install on [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt install libssl-dev
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
node -v
npm -v
npm install -g appium
```