# Command line error while installing "Appium" on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, appium

I used this command to install `Appium` on my machine:

```
npm install -g appium
```

& I got this error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! cwd /home/asus
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/appium
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/appium' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can get some idea from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android

Answer (score 1):

Linux: 
•   Download and install Latest Java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
•   Download and install latest Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
•   Configure path to ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME in .bash profile
•   Configure path to Platform-tools and tools folder in .bash profile
•   Use command gedit.bashrc to open bash profile

Steps to get appium working on ubuntu pc :

Install ruby: Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
Install linux brew:Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter 
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

set path for brew

Type: gedit.bashrc at terminal and copy paste following into the .bashrc file

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Install node:Paste the below commands one by one  at terminal and hit enter

```
brew update
brew install node
brew link node
```

Install appium

```
npm install -g appium


npm install wd
```

To start appium: Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

```
appium
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. But when i tried this "brew update" I got this "No command 'brew' found" .  I searched the Ubuntu forums but did not get exact solution for brew command.

Comment: ADD this to your .bahrc profile

export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"