# Appium does not start with non sudo installation

Tags: npm, homebrew, appium

Platform: Ubuntu 14.10
Appium - 1.3.7

One similar question I had come across -

[How to setup Appium in Ubuntu for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android)

and following suggestion, I install npm via HomeBrew

And eventually, appium execution fails with error -

```
error: Appium will not work if used or installed with sudo. Please rerun/install as a non-root user. If you had to install Appium using `sudo npm install -g appium`, the solution is to reinstall Node using a method (Homebrew, for example) that doesn't require sudo to install global npm packages.
```

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently I was on  wrong directory when invoking invoking appium. I should be in /node-v0.12.2-linux-x64/bin$ and invoke appium.
even though I was in wrong directory, the error message I received was so descriptive (and misleading) that it made me believe that I installed appium in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Appium allows to run under sudo since 1.2.3: [source](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.2.3)

Comment: I am running Appium v1.3.7 and have error with sudo

Comment: @Tarun install node with sudo using homebrew. Try to run reset.sh

Comment: sudo + homebrew does not help, what is reset.sh ?

Comment: You can find reset.sh in [Appium source code](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/reset.sh)

Comment: Hm. Are you running from source code? Where do you keep source code folder? Try to run reset.sh with option --hardcore like that: `sh reset.sh --hardcore`, it will completely reinstall all needed Node.js modules.  If that won't help, then completely reinstall node and npm using this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: apparently I was on wrong directory, please see the my own response to the question