# How to install appium in elemantary os

Tags: appium

I am new to appium. How can I install appium in elemantory os. I downloaded the appium from official site. A dmg file is downloaded. But dont know how to move further.

Answer (score 0):

.dmg file is OS X package. You don`t need it.

According to this page on Appium`s official web site: http://appium.io/downloads.html
Appium Desktop app is available only on Windows and OS platforms.

On Linux you need to install it as Node package.

1. Appium won't run if node/npm are install as a privileged (sudo) user. So you`ll have to use another way to install them. You can use Linux version of Homebrew( https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew ) or download node binaries ( https://nodejs.org/en/download/ ) and place them in your home folder.
2. You may add an environmental variable for appium. To do it open ~/.bashrc file and add this string to the end:

*export PATH=$PATH:/bin*

And then reread that file:

*source ~/.bashrc*

3. Install Appium:
   *npm install -g appium*
4. Run appium:
   *appium&*

Elementary OS is very similar to Ubuntu. You may found a lot of information how to install Appium on Ubuntu. For example check this link:
[How to setup Appium in Ubuntu for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android)