# npm -install error ,I can't install appium

Tags: npm, appium

I'm Appium new user I have some error ,when I use the NPM command (linux),I have update my ("nvm" and "npm" )version.

I'm follow Click [here]([How to setup Appium in Ubuntu for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android) " to setup my appium.

How can I do for next step!

```
 root@hauying-yoga-linux:/home/hauying# npm install -g grunt-cli
 npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
 npm ERR!     at Unpack.extractOpts.filter 
 (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/tar.js:245:19)
 npm ERR!     at Unpack.[consumeHeader] 
 (/usr/lib/nodejs/tar/lib/parse.js:134:48)
 npm ERR!     at Unpack.[consumeChunkSub] 
 (/usr/lib/nodejs/tar/lib/parse.js:385:30)
 npm ERR!     at Unpack.[consumeChunk] 
 (/usr/lib/nodejs/tar/lib/parse.js:362:30)
 npm ERR!     at Unpack.write 
 (/usr/lib/nodejs/tar/lib/parse.js:309:25)
 npm ERR!     at Unzip.ondata (_stream_readable.js:667:20)
 npm ERR!     at Unzip.emit (events.js:189:13)
 npm ERR!     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
 npm ERR!     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
 npm ERR!     at Unzip.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
 npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
 npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
 npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

 npm ERR! System Linux 4.19.37-5rodete4-amd64
 npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" 
 "grunt-cli"
 npm ERR! cwd /home/hauying
 npm ERR! node -v v10.15.2
 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /home/hauying/npm-debug.log
 npm ERR! not ok code 0
 root@hauying-yoga-linux:/home/hauying#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fixed.
because my node and npm version too old , I'm update my document will install in my computer.