# Trouble installing a module as a global variable -- /usr/bin/env not a directory

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu, github

I am attempting to install the node.js module 'javascripting' (source code can be found: https://github.com/sethvincent/javascripting) and have been unable to install it as a global variable to run through the terminal.

After installing node.js I attempted to install javascripting with the line: npm install --global javascripting

While it is my understand that this should work, it only downloads the module but does not set it as a global variable to be run in terminal.

The error I receive when attempting to run it as a global variable is "/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory".

After receiving this error I attempted to move the module to /usr/bin/env from the directory it installed in (usr/local/lib/node_modules/javascripting). Unfortunately, I was not able to move the files because /usr/bin/env is not a directory, rather it seems to be some sort of executable java file (usr/bin is a directory).

I am a bit lost and would love some advice on either how to install the module as a working global variable or whether there is another way to run the module without installing it as a global variable.

Comment: Did you also `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`? This will give you a symlink so you can use `node` in addition to `nodejs`.

Comment: FYI /usr/bin/env is a linux binary (ELF, not Java) and sets up a specific clean environment for whatever command it calls. This can be used to make sure that a program executes the way it is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if the node.js binary (`node`) is not installed in the $PATH anywhere.

if you run `env node` by itself, you will get the same error. It looks like this may be an Ubuntu bug: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3911

Try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` - that will symlink the node.js binary from the name Ubuntu gave it to the name it's supposed to have.

EDIT:
As mscdex pointed out in a comment (and as mentioned at the end of the bug I linked), there's a legacy package you can install that should create this symlink.

`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

The bug I linked above indicates that there are probably other problems with Ubuntu / Debian's default node.js package, and recommends you install your own either from the PPA mentioned there or from source.

You'll probably need to follow the advice in [NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo) as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answers!  I installed the legacy package to create the symlink as was suggested by both mscdex and stonecrusher and it worked completely.

The only command needed to solve the problem was the: sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy one cited in both posts.

I greatly appreciate all of the help!

Edit: per suggestion from stonecrusher I switched this to a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: In case you installed node via [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) then don't forget to run a `nvm use 0.x.y` or a `nvm use stable`

Comment: Is there anyway to create symlink without root access?