# EACESS error when executing Bower

Tags: linux, node.js, polymer, bower

I'm trying to set up Polymer project using Bower.

I am successfully installed Nodejs and Bower, but when I am tried to execute

```
   init bower
```

in the command line, I always get this error

```
Stack trace:
Error: EACCES, open '/kuda/bower.json'

Console trace:
Trace
at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:82:17)
at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:110:22)
at Logger.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Logger.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:40:20
at _rejected (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
at Promise.when (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to go to `/usr/lib/node_modules/...`, so this is a permission problem.

A fool would now try `sudo -E bower init --allow-root` but that's not really a solution (although it works). **Do not do this if you do not know exactly what it does and what the risks are**, that counts for all `sudo` commands. 'Just sudo when it doesn't work' is really not a good solution.

You probably ran `sudo npm install -g bower` when you installed bower, because without `sudo` it didn't work. When that happens, the owner of the bower program is not you, but the root user and thus you have no access to it.

Try this:

1. Delete bower
2. Follw this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712034/4269144
3. Do `npm install -g bower`, without sudo!
4. Try `init bower` again

Comment: thanks for your reply luc, i already followed  the post http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712034/4269144, and now I am able install bower without sudo, but I'm still getting the same error when executing bower init. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Does the `npm` directory exist? Otherwise try `mkdir ~/npm`. Also, you could try to do `source ~/.bashrc`.