# How to Upgrade Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.4 to any higher version?

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

There are many questions in stackoverflow and in other blogs which says just execute the below command to upgrade-

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@5.1.1
```

After executing the above command in my terminal i get the following-

```
 /usr/bin/cordova -> /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@5.1.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── cordova-lib@5.1.1 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.1.0, unorm@1.3.3, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, xcode@0.6.7, rc@0.5.2, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, npm@1.3.4, elementtree@0.1.6, d8@0.4.4, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, glob@4.0.6, request@2.47.0, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.8, plist@1.1.0, init-package-json@1.6.0, tar@1.0.2, cordova-js@4.0.0)
```

After that if i execute-

```
cordova -g -v
```

i get **3.5.0-0.2.4** as the version. Couldn't find any solution to upgrade from 3.5.0-0.2.4 to higher version , any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My guess is that sudo is hosing you up here.  Running `sudo cordova -v` should spit out that version you installed.  I try to avoid using sudo to install npm modules.  If you have issues, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Comment: Wohooo! Thanks mate your link helped , specifically this one. - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24404451/1084806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that sudo is hosing you up here. Running sudo cordova -v should spit out that version you installed. I try to avoid using sudo to install npm modules.

This answer here has a lot of solid solutions in it: [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

There are some other solutions not included in that thread as well.  I tried to find this answer yesterday to link you to as well, but was unable too: [NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo).

I also had this happen when I first installed node, and based on that answer this was the quickest solution: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`.  That being said there is a concern about playing with permissions like that.

While I haven't tried this myself, apparently installing node from this repository also resolves the error.  After removing node, run:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash - 
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo npm update -g cordova` or if you want a specific version for exemple `sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0`.

Check with `cordova -v` and then if you want to update your platform, here Android, `cordova platform update android`