# I am not able install angular 4 cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Must run your command as user and install npm + angular cli globally

Comment: run `sudo npm...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```