# "Please try running this command again as Root/Administrator" error on gulp install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gulp

I am trying to install gulp in my project ,when executing this command

`npm install -g gulp`

I am getting error like this:

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I have successfully installed nodejs on my **ubuntu** machine.
How can i solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `sudo npm install -g gulp`