# Unable to install react on ubuntu and following error occurs when npm install -g less is run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, npm

```
$ npm install -g less
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/less failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lntinfotech/.npm/_logs/2018-10-08T10_00_47_468Z-debug.log
lntinfotech@nikhil:~$ npm help config
lntinfotech@nikhil:~$ npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib
npm ERR! path /usr/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Comment: are you behind a VPN ?

Comment: using ubuntu? try installing with sudo, and if it installs with sudo then we know the problem. So check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo?rq=1

Comment: It’s a permission issue, you have to install with sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with `sudo`.

```
sudo npm i -g create-react-app
```