# npm install -g react-native-cli - showing error

Tags: react-native

heckPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!

Comment: your question need to be edited & formatted. You should explain what did you tried and show some code that you think it's relative to your issue

Comment: I think this is a permission related issue. If you are using the Linux operating system add sudo before the command and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to permission related issue, use `sudo npm i -d react-native-cli`

Answer (score 1):

See if the answers from this post helps: [NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo)

I had a similar problem and I added "sudo" with the command as follows:
*sudo* **npm install -g aws-cdk**